# Provisioning Azure Data Factory with Managed private endpoints using Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I am developing a Terraform Script to provision the Azure Data Factory that reads the data from the storage account and updates the Azure SQL Server. It works.

[image]

I have created the Private Endpoints for both the Storage account and Azure SQL Server

Storage Account Private Endpoint

[image]

SQL Server Private Endpoint

[image]

Now, I want to update the Azure Data factory to use these private endpoints. I do understand that I need to setup the IR & managed private endpoints in the Azure Data Factory.

How do I achieve this using Terraform? Below is my script so far

```
# Create a Data Factory
resource "azurerm_data_factory" "terraform-demo-factory" {
  name                = "tf-demo-factory"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  github_configuration {
    account_name = "kavija"
    branch_name = "main"
    git_url = "https://github.com/kavija/azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
    repository_name = "azure-data-factory-etl-demo"
    root_folder = "/"
  }

  tags = {
        creator = "Terraform"
        project = "terraform-demo"
  }

  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.id]
  }
}

# Assign role to ADF Service Principal
resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "uai_adf_storage_access_reader" {
  scope              = module.storage_account.storage_account_id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Account Reader"
  principal_id       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.principal_id
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "uai_adf_storage_access_blob_contributor" {
  scope              = module.storage_account.storage_account_id
  role_definition_name = "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
  principal_id       = azurerm_user_assigned_identity.uai_adf.principal_id
}
```

Also, Is there a way to create a Private Endpoint for Azure Data Factory itself? so that it will be with in my VNET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to setup using the below terraform code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "selfhostvm" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-VM"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.example.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_B1s"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${var.prefix}-VM"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    timezone           = "Pacific Standard Time"
    provision_vm_agent = true
  }
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_self_hosted" "host" {
  name            = "${var.prefix}IntegrationRuntimeHOST"
  data_factory_id = azurerm_data_factory.host.id
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "test" {
  name                 = "${var.prefix}-EXT"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.selfhostvm.id
  publisher            = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                 = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.10"
  settings = jsonencode({
    "fileUris"         = ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kvija85/install-df-agent/main/gatewayInstall.ps1"],
    "commandToExecute" = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File gatewayInstall.ps1 ${azurerm_data_factory_integration_runtime_self_hosted.host.primary_authorization_key} && timeout /t 120"
  })
}
```